# Animating TimePicker hour change

Tags: android, android-animation, timepicker

I'm building an app, and in it the user needs to pick an hour.
I used TimePicker for this, and everything works fine, but I want to increment the hours by 1 if the user scrolled down the minutes and got again to 0.

I managed to do this by setting  **OnTimeChangedListener** , but the thing is , that the numbers just change, and it doesn't animate the hours number change.

is it possible to progrematically call the animation to increment the hours by 1?

thanks.